# Finding correlations between a set of binary features and a single numerical value

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, correlation, hierarchical-data

Say I have the following dataset (small sample), see images:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNn6P.png)
[Acyclic Directed Graph corresponding to Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srDN2.png)

Where patients can have a number of diseases (F0->F8) that are on/off and a single numerical value (representing something like life expectancy or w/e). The diseases correspond to an hierarchical terminology system (like ICD-9) as seen in the 2nd image. Does there exist any approaches in machine learning or statistics (preferably Python) to find correlations between the single numerical value and the sequence of binary values for diseases that are turned on/off? Any help or point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please try to include images directly in the Question so others can see them directly.

Comment: I would, but one needs >10 reputation in order to embed images into your question.

Comment: Ok, That is a drawback then. I'll give you +1 so you should be able to do this.